# Read multiple types in a collection using MongoDB C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, mongodb-.net-driver

I try to create a timeline collection that contians multiple types. I have no problem to insert the type or read a specific type. But when i want a list of all types for a specific user, then i got problem.

```
public interface ITimelineItem
{
    public string EventType { get; set; }
    public string EventId { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}

public class TimelineItemBase
{
    public string EventType { get; set; }
    public string EventId { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public List<MediaInfo> Media { get; set; }
}

public class AlbumEvent : TimelineItemBase, ITimelineItem
{
    public MediaAlbum Album { get; set; }
}

public class BirthdayEvent : TimelineItemBase, ITimelineItem
{
}

public class BlogPostEvent : TimelineItemBase, ITimelineItem
{
    public BlogPost Post { get; set; }
}

public static class TimelineRepo
{
    private static IMongoCollection<T> GetCollection<T>() where T : ITimelineItem
    {
        return Connection.Database.GetCollection<T>("Timeline");
    }

    public static async Task Add<T>(T data) where T : ITimelineItem
    {
        data.EventType = typeof(T).Name;

        var coll = GetCollection<T>();
        await coll.InsertOneAsync(data);
    }

    public static async Task<List<T>> GetEventsByUserId<T>(Guid userId) where T : ITimelineItem
    {
        return await GetCollection<T>().Find(p => p.UserId == userId).ToListAsync();
    }
}


public class GenerateTimeline
{
    public static async Task<List<ITimelineViewModel>> GetTimeline(Guid userId)
    {
        var items = await TimelineRepo.GetEventsByUserId<???>(userId);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item is BirthdayEvent be)
            {
                // do work
            }
            else if (item is BlogPostEvent bp)
            {
                // do work
            }
            else if (item is AlbumEvent ae)
            {
                // do work
                ae.Album.Header
            }
        }
    }
}


[HttpGet("/api/user/{userid}/timeline"), Authorize]
public async Task<List<ITimelineViewModel>> GetTimeline(Guid userId)
{
    return await GenerateTimeline.GetTimeline(userId);
}
```

How can I get a list containing different types for a user? Or is this a bad way to create a timeline for users?

Comment: Yes, there's no way for any kind of serialiser to choose the correct type when reading the JSON back so this wouldn't work.

Comment: I understand that, but i store the type in EventType so it should be possible to serialise it back to the correct object type?

Comment: Yes, but how would you know which type to deserialise it to beforehand?

Comment: MongoDB can deal with multiple document types that are derived from a base class (polymorphism). You are basically implementing it yourself. Maybe this link can help: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/

Comment: What i did was to read all as BsonDocument, loop all items and check property EventType  and then select the correct class, example:
foreach(var item in items) {
    var type = item["EventType"];
    if(type == nameOf(BirthdayEvent) 
         list.Add(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BirthdayEvent>(item));
}
Is that a bad solution?